# Can i open / focus a different tab within the same domain that i didn't open myself?

Tags: javascript, browser, focus, window-object, broadcast-channel

I have two instances of my Angular App running in two different tabs, I would like to be able to let the user switch between them by pressing a button on the site.

I can communicate between the instances using the [Broadcast Channel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API), however calling `window.focus()` inside the inactive tab doesn't do anything. Since the messages are serialized / deserialized I also can't just send the window object over the channel.

I also tried getting access to the window instance of the inactive tab by setting window.name in it and then calling `window.open('', otherName)` in the active tab. That also doesn't work and just spawns a new empty tab.

A solution would have to work for existing instances of the app **opened by the user**, I know this would work if i just window.open'ed the second instance from the first one (Or iframed it or something similiar). I also know this would work using a browser extension but that also doesn't fit my use case.

If this simply isn't possible I will just build "tabs" into the application itself but just thought i would ask first since this way would be easier.